# How many Stack Exchange sites are there?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tour

According to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/), the network has 94 Q&A sites:

[image]

But the new [about page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about) disagrees:

[image]

My first guess was that the about page count included private betas, but according to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) there are only two of them currently (ELL and Magento). Tim Stone has a [better explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165241/how-many-stack-exchange-sites-are-there#comment482337_165241) for the inconsistency:

> There are 98 sites, two of which are private betas, and two of which are Meta Stack Overflow and StackApps, which are only `main_site` Q&A sites in the technical sense. The about page should show 94 sites.

Whatever the reason, the counts shouldn't really be different, let's pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Bonus bug: The counts in the first screenshot should be in the same line.

Comment: A manual count of the [all sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) list gives me 96...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: So the answer is the average of both counts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, both counts are wrong. Even better ;)

Comment: No freehand circles...

Comment: There are 98 sites, two of which are private betas, and two of which are Meta Stack Overflow and StackApps, which are only `main_site` Q&A sites in the technical sense. The about page should show 94 sites.

Comment: @tim no, MSO is listed. A51 isn't

Comment: @Manishearth I know it's listed, it just doesn't "count". Area 51 is automatically excluded because it's not returned by the API.

Comment: I dare someone to close this as a duplicate of the "S" bugs...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed.

The 4-site discrepancy was due to Meta Stack Overflow, Stack Apps, and 2 private beta sites.

Comment: [See what happens when you no longer work here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251957/difference-in-communities-on-main-site)? We need you back :D

Answer (score 8):

To get an updated count, you can run this query on Data Explorer

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1019093/how-many-stackexchange-non-meta-sites-are-there

```
SELECT count(name) FROM sys.databases
where (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')
and database_id > 5
```

The answer, as of today, is **174**, which matches the homepage

[image]