# Difference in number of communities on main site

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, stack-exchange-button

[image]

I assume the difference in the number of Stack Exchange sites/communities is a mistake... correct?

Comment: Maybe private betas are counted in one but not in the other?

Comment: Regression of [this old bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165241/how-many-stack-exchange-sites-are-there) that was fixed for a while.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the below sites will be counted in the "higher" count and won't be counted in the tour page number:

1. Sites during Private Beta phase
2. Experimental sites, e.g. https://cs50.stackexchange.com
3. [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) which isn't really a Q&A site.

The above gets a strong positive nudge from the fact the [full sites list on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites) also showing the "low count", and none of the above are listed there.

Comment: So I guess the difference will go down to 3 in "at least one more day", as Woodworking's Private Beta comes to a close.

Comment: @Werner yup, most likely. (it will then say "Each of our 138 communities..." :))

Comment: @Werner see my edit, I was wrong about one of the sites.

Comment: [142 vs 137](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yZrIB.png)... whaaaat?

Comment: @Werner https://civicrm.stackexchange.com in private beta too now. When both will be out of private beta it would be 142 vs. 139. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have removed the duplicate content from my original question [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262146/area-51-site-missing-count-of-stack-exchange-network-sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262146/area-51-site-missing-count-of-stack-exchange-network-sites) Please take a look at it.

Comment: Btw, no more edx.

Comment: @nicael yeah, that information was relevant only at the time of posting, thinking of a way to edit it.