# Area 51 site missing count of Stack Exchange Network sites

Tags: feature-request, area-51, top-bar, tooltips

The count shown on the Area 51 topbar sites-switcher tooltip (hover over Stack Exchange logo on the top-left) is ***missing the count*** of Stack Exchange Network sites.

Area 51 topbar sites-switcher tooltip says:

> A list of all Stack Exchange sites

Whereas, on StackExchange.com it says "A list of all **154** Stack Exchange sites" and most of the subdomains i.e. *****.stackexchange.com shows "A list of all **149** Stack Exchange sites".

But, as for the Area 51 tooltip goes, it's totally ***missing*** the count.

Here is the screenshot of it:

> [image]

Can anyone please explain this?

**P.S.**
My original question was marked [as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251957/difference-in-number-of-communities-on-main-site) by Shadow Wizard. But it was not exactly duplicate. I have removed the duplicate content from this question. Please note that [Werner's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251957/difference-in-number-of-communities-on-main-site) is about the *difference* in *number* of communities on Stack Exchange site whereas my question is about "missing count".

Comment: "A list of all 100+ Stack Exchange sites"

Comment: I am forced to delete my answer as I got the downvote and downvote is  not the reason I'm deleting my answer, It's because of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261937/where-did-my-newly-posted-question-go) I reported

Comment: I just opted out from "new-nav" and I can see my question. Now I  know why the high-reps have opted out.

Comment: @Dronehinge I have modified the question and casted vote for reopen but I guess it needs 5 votes. Could you please read my updated post and see if you can cast a reopen vote.

Comment: That's not a bug. Retagged and reopened.

Comment: And the original question was duplicate, you now ask a totally different thing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for retagging. Actually, the "bug" tag was added by user Shokhet and not me. It's in the edit history.

Comment: It was added when it was still a bug. Anyway, all good now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Area 51 has no way of knowing the number of sites in the network. It's a separate (and old) codebase and it doesn't have access to the database that has all this good stuff.

"No way of knowing" is perhaps a bit exaggerated (there's always API calls, after all), but the reality is that adding this in isn't gonna be trivial. Doing an extra call is out, changing the API that currently returns the site switcher UI is possible, but seems like too much effort for something fairly minor.

Basically, the answer is "meh, it's Area 51". :)

P.S. I'm not marking the question as status-anything since this is a reasonable enough request. We might do it someday? Who knows. I just wanted to explain why things are the way they are at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. Like you have said ""meh, it's Area 51" I had the same feeling about this one but just thought of asking. Who knows someday when things get standardize across the network this will resolve itself.